# Eclipse, can't see output if program crashes

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a segmentation fault and my program crashes.
I still want to be able to see the print I did right before the crash.

I tried debugging it and went over the "cout" line and still I can't see the output during or after the crash.

Basically I have a vector iterator and would like to see its contents but it's really hard using the debugger. If you have a solution for this one it will be better than the solving the output case..

Thanks :)

Comment: which compiler? In visual studio and gcc debugging a vector is quite different

Comment: It seems like you don't flush the stream, try using the [`flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) function or the [`flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) manipulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cerr` instead of `cout` because `cout` buffers its output. `cerr` is slower in most situations, but always use it for debug prints.

[More information](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cerr/)